# Handling dynamic Routes with Diff2Html from its file list in Angular

Tags: angular, diff2html

I am using [Diff2Html-UI](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) it with Angular 13 and I am struggling with the links (href) in the file list. Since they have by default this form:
`<a href="**#d2h-953324**" class="d2h-file-name">somefile.xml</a>`
As one can see in the code ([github link](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html/blob/3732d5924906959f40f19b4ba8870c33d16af793/src/file-list-renderer.ts#L15)) those are generated via hash from the filename. And since I do not know the routes a developtime  I have no way of including them in my routing module.

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>{{comparisonInfo}}</span><br>
    <div id="diffElement"></div>
</div>
```

TypeScript

```
import {Diff2HtmlUI, Diff2HtmlUIConfig} from 'diff2html/lib/ui/js/diff2html-ui-slim.js';
...
let diff = "unified diff string from git fetched by a rest call"
const targetElement = document.getElementById('diffElement');
const configuration : Diff2HtmlUIConfig = {
   drawFileList: this.fileSummary,
   matching: 'lines',
   highlight: true
};
const diff2htmlUi = new Diff2HtmlUI(targetElement, diff, configuration);
diff2htmlUi.draw();
diff2htmlUi.highlightCode();
```

I have changed the LocationStrategy to:
`{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }`
but that of course leads to a 404 Page not found.

I was trying to change the [file-summary-template](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html/blob/3732d5924906959f40f19b4ba8870c33d16af793/src/templates/file-summary-line.mustache#L4) to add a basepath, but I couldn't get it to work. To be honest I am not that good in angular to translate the suggestion in one of the tests into something workable in angular. I would like to avoid adding another dependency like hogan.js for this.

[Link to the test](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html/blob/3732d5924906959f40f19b4ba8870c33d16af793/src/__tests__/hogan-cache-tests.ts#L36)

Is this the right path to go? Has anyone experienced similar issues?